# How to create a group of lines in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, line

I want to be able to draw lets say 4 different lines and group them so I can be able to treat the 4 lines like a single object, I tried to do this:

```
    Group groupCFE = new Group();
    groupCFE.getChildren().addAll(line1, line2, line3, line4, line5);
```

and then treat it like this:

```
    groupCFE.setStroke(Color.RED);
```

but its not possible, is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this use the class Polyline:

```
Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
polyline.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
760.0, 637.0,
780.0, 637.0,
780.0, 637.0,
786.0, 630.0,
786.0, 630.0,
822.0, 630.0,
822.0, 630.0,
832.0, 639.0,
849.0, 639.0,});
polyline.setStroke(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a subclass of `Region`, add all lines as child elements. Setting stroke on the region won't automatically set it on the children though. You would have to forward the value by registering a listener on the region's property.

Depending on your use case using a `Polyline` may be a better solution, as you suggested.